# Unable to write files to localhost and network share

Tags: python, server, localhost, cross-domain, tornado

I have a python tornado installed, and initially it was working as per design like
Scanning a document from PC using python agent and send to server URL

1. Scanning is done using python and tornado
2. Now if I write these files to server using binary write it's not working and no data is avail be on server URL after completion of Task

I have tried to set origin using `http://localhost` or `http://IP Address` but not successful

code is as

```
def set_default_headers(self):
    self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with")
    self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS')
def check_origin(self, origin):
    allowed = ["http://localhost", "http://192.168.1.1"]
    if origin in allowed:
     print("allowed", origin)
    return 1
```

Please help me to figure out this issue

Comment: maybe problem is `scanning` - maybe it create wrong file.

Comment: I think it would need to run code to see problem. I don't know what can be problem by it can be in any place - not only in headers.